# When trying to send an API request the very first API request gets failed each day or after some time lap

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The APIM is running 24/7 on my server, sometimes I have experienced below response. But in the very next request passes successfully. This is happening intermittently,have not identified any pattern on this.

`{ "code": "404", "type": "Status report", "message": "Not Found", "description": "The requested resource is not available." }`

Comment: It seems this is coming from your backend.

Comment: What is your APIM version?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tenants, and the tenant has been inactive for some time, it will be unloaded. If you invoke an API in a tenant which was unloaded, there's a possibility of encountering such an error in the first invocation as tenant needs to be loaded. Any subsequent invocations will be successful since the tenant is now loaded.